# how to make multiple line text file as dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, nlp

have the mess text file, need to convert it to csv file format, how to do that for example:

hello this is first line.
this is both lines are one raw.

hello this is second line.
this is both lines are one raw.

how to convert multiple lines of text like a paragraph convert them into data frame or cv format

Answer (score 0):

You can first read the lines and then pass the list to a dataframe:

#### Example File:

`sample.txt`:

```
hello this is first line. this is both lines are one raw.
hello this is second line. this is both lines are one raw.
```

#### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read the lines and create a Dataframe
with open("/content/sample.txt", "r") as file_handle:
  df = pd.DataFrame(file_handle.readlines())

# Save Dataframe to CSV
df.to_csv("output/file.csv")
```